# Migrating from background page to service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In January 2023 the extensions with the Manifest V2 will stop working, and I try to migrate to V3 but I have the problem that I have to migrate to service worker

With the V2 manifest I had my background.js file

```
const browser = chrome || browser

const tabQuery = (options, params = {}) => new Promise(res => {
    if (!options.countPinnedTabs) params.pinned = false
    browser.tabs.query(params, tabs => res(tabs))
})

const windowRemaining = options =>
    tabQuery(options, { currentWindow: true })
        .then(tabs => options.maxWindow - tabs.length)

const totalRemaining = options =>
    tabQuery(options)
        .then(tabs => options.maxTotal - tabs.length)

const updateBadge = options => {
    if (!options.displayBadge) {
        browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: "" })
        return;
    }

    Promise.all([windowRemaining(options), totalRemaining(options)])
    .then(remaining => {
        browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: Math.min(...remaining).toString()
        });
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
            color: "#7e7e7e"
        })
    })
}

const detectTooManyTabsInWindow = options => new Promise(res => {
    tabQuery(options, { currentWindow: true }).then(tabs => {
        if (options.maxWindow < 1) return;
        if (tabs.length > options.maxWindow) res("window");
    });
})

const detectTooManyTabsInTotal = options => new Promise(res => {
    tabQuery(options).then(tabs => {
        if (options.maxTotal < 1) return;
        if (tabs.length > options.maxTotal) res("total");
    });
})

const getOptions = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    browser.storage.sync.get("defaultOptions", (defaults) => {
        browser.storage.sync.get(defaults.defaultOptions, (options) => {
            res(options);
        })
    })
})

const displayAlert = (options, place) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (!options.displayAlert) { return res(false) }

    const replacer = (match, p1, offset, string) => {
        switch (p1) {
            case "place":
            case "which":
                return place === "window" ?
                    "one window" : "total";
                break;

            case "maxPlace":
            case "maxWhich":
                return options[
                    "max" + capitalizeFirstLetter(place)
                ];
                break;

            default:
                return options[p1] || "?";
        }
    };

    const renderedMessage = options.alertMessage.replace(
        /{\s*(\S+)\s*}/g,
        replacer
    )
    alert(renderedMessage);
})

let tabCount = -1
let previousTabCount = -1
let amountOfTabsCreated = -1

const updateTabCount = () => new Promise(res => browser.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
    if (tabs.length == tabCount) {
        return res(amountOfTabsCreated);
    }

    previousTabCount = tabCount
    tabCount = tabs.length
    amountOfTabsCreated =
        ~previousTabCount ? tabCount - previousTabCount : 0
    res(amountOfTabsCreated)
}))

let passes = 0;

const handleExceedTabs = (tab, options, place) => {
    console.log(place)
    if (options.exceedTabNewWindow && place === "window") {
        browser.windows.create({ tabId: tab.id, focused: true});
    } else {
        browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    }
}

const handleTabCreated = tab => options => {
    return Promise.race([
        detectTooManyTabsInWindow(options),
        detectTooManyTabsInTotal(options)
    ])
    .then((place) => updateTabCount().then(amountOfTabsCreated => {
        if (passes > 0) {
            console.log("passed with pass no. ", passes)
            passes--;
            return;
        }
        console.log("amountOfTabsCreated", amountOfTabsCreated)
        displayAlert(options, place)
        if (amountOfTabsCreated === 1) {
            handleExceedTabs(tab, options, place);
            app.update()
        } else if (amountOfTabsCreated > 1) {
            passes = amountOfTabsCreated - 1
        } else if (amountOfTabsCreated === -1) {
            handleExceedTabs(tab, options, place);
            app.update()
        } else {
            throw new Error("weird: multiple tabs closed after tab created")
        }
    }))
}

const app = {
    init: function() {
        browser.storage.sync.set({
            defaultOptions: {
                maxTotal: 20,
                maxWindow: 20,
                exceedTabNewWindow: false,
                displayAlert: true,
                countPinnedTabs: false,
                displayBadge: true,
                alertMessage: chrome.i18n.getMessage("string_7")
            }
        });

        browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab =>
            getOptions().then(handleTabCreated(tab))
        )

        console.log("init", this)
        browser.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(app.update)
        browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(app.update)
        browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(app.update)
        browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(app.update)
    },
    update: () => {
        updateTabCount();
        getOptions().then(updateBadge)
    }
};

app.init();
app.update();

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Any suggestions on how to convert it for service worker to work with Manifest V3?

Thank you and I look forward to your comments